# How do I find out which JAR application is not using?

Tags: java, jar

In our application through the process of developing a lot of JAR files has been collected. How can I filter out those, which are not used by application anymore? On some easy way?

Comment: Good question. I would also like to know this :)

Comment: I think this is one of java's biggest flaws, the fact that the dynamic dependencies are impossible to nail down 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure your you can exercise your application so that it uses all it's jars, you can create a simple perl script:

```
while (<>) {
    $l{$1}++ if m/\s+from\s+(.+\.jar)/;
}

for $l (keys(%l)) {
    print "$l\n";
}
```

(lets name it list_jars.pl) and feed it the output of a verbose run:

```
java -verbose -jar YOUR_APP.jar | perl list_jars.pl
```

which should list all sources of classes loaded.

Comment: What if I have web application archive (war)?

Comment: The perl script parses the verbose classloader output, for a web-app you should be able to add -verbose to the startup parameters and parse the resulting standard output logging. (This will probably show jars that are used by the servlet container too.)

Answer (score 1):

if youre using maven, there's a mojo for that : mvn dependency:analyze 
if not, i dont know of any easy way. the hard way would involve bytecode analysis of all the compiled classes of your project to inspect imports ...

Comment: No...  But maven will catch dependencies declared in the pom.xml but not obvious in the code (frameworks and dynamically loaded drivers for example.)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [stan](http://stan4j.com/). it's a structure analyzer for java, and it gave me very good results.

You can visually see which jar are used and which not.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script which removes them one by one from your build path, compiles the project and checks for build errors. The script would assemble a list of unused jars. Should be easy to write in bash/python.

This solution cannot track runtime dependencies based on reflection (see my comment below).

Comment: That will find compile-time errors, but not errors that result at runtime from failures of delayed class loading. Especially with complex frameworks such things are quite common. Even worse is when the framework picks one available class for a specified interface, and the behaviour is subtly different depending on which implementation is actually used. I strongly recommend running a full integration test after you think you are done.

Comment: You are right, this solution doesn't handle that case. But I think it is quite impossible to do that automatically if you use some advanced reflection. What would you do, extract all the strings in the code that may be matching a class name:>?

Comment: You can also do this via the Eclipse IDE by removing items from the .classpath one at a time and rebuilding the project.  When stuff turns red you removed one that's in use. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write your own ClassLoader, inheriting from java.lang.ClassLoader, that logs the paths of loaded classes? That still doesn't solve the problem of ensuring full coverage of all classes loaded during all possible code paths, though